# Can $\limsup = \liminf$ only almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, independence, limsup-and-liminf

Might be a dumb question once you get to Kolmogorov but whether or not $A_n$'s are independent, is it possible

$$\liminf A_n \ne \limsup A_n$$

but $$P(\liminf A_n) = P(\limsup A_n)$$?

Possible cases to consider:

- $A_n$'s are/aren't independent.
- $\liminf A_n$ is/isn't empty.
- $\limsup A_n$ is/isn't empty.
- $\limsup A_n$ has probability 0/probability 1.
- $\liminf A_n$ has probability 0/probability 1.

Answer (score 1):

Both events are 0,1. Notice that by definition if $\omega\in \liminf_nA_n$, then $\omega\in \limsup A_n$. So if $\liminf A_n\neq \limsup A_n$, then this implies there's some set $R$ which belongs to one but not the other. If $P(R)=0$ then everything is fine. But if $P(R)>0$, then this implies $P(\mbox{liminf}A_n)=0$ and $P(\mbox{limsup}A_n)=1$

Comment: Alex R., thanks. Are the events 0,1 even if $A_n$ not independent?

Comment: @BCLC: Certainly not. For example, you could let all of the $A_n$ be _the same_ event with any probability you want.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right so it's possible if $A_n$'s are not independent? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is easily possible -- for example, let $X$ be a (single) normal distributed variable and
$$ A_n = \begin{cases} X\in(0,1] & \text{when $n$ is odd} \\
X \in[0,1) & \text{when $n$ is even} \end{cases} $$
These $A_n$s are far from independent, so the 0-1 law does not apply here.